# Mongodb not authorized on admin to execute listDatabases command

Tags: mongodb

After droping mongodb user ,**not able to reconnect mongo again without
 authentication**

i had created [superuser](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles) **tomuser**

**my command sequence in ubuntu terminal**

1.`use admin`

2.`db.dropUser('tomuser')
    true
    exit`

3.`sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop`

4.`sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start`

5.`restart pc`

6.`mongo --port 27017`

7.`> show dbs
2016-01-14T16:03:55.420+0530 listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47`

---

I am getting above error!! `not authorized on admin to execute command`

so **,not able to connect mongodb after dropping user ..?**

is there any thing missing ...?

Comment: OK.. What is your question?

Comment: @MHakvoort i have edit question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1st way

I think there should be another user in the `db.system.users`. If so, please use the saved user to log in.

If there is NO users in the `db.system.users`

```
> db.system.users.find({})
  null
```

we can access `mongodb` through `mongo --port 27017`.

> 2nd way - Usual cause of problem

**use**    `sudo mongod --port 27017`

**instead of** `sudo mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

*note : **--auth** is only required when **username** & **password** **authentication** is setup*