# execute raw mondodb query from java mongodb driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm developing a web application to run native mongo query through java driver, so that I could see the results in good UI. I didn't find a straight way to do that but running js functions seems to be one way to do that.

I can run the following script from mongo shell.

```
rs1:PRIMARY> function showShortedItems() { return db.Items.find({});}

rs1:PRIMARY> showShortedItems()
```

[But while trying same thing from java driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.runCommand/#definition), nope.

```
    val db = connection.getDatabase(Database.Name)
    val command = new BasicDBObject("eval", "function() { return db.Items.find(); }")    
    val result = db.runCommand(command)
```

**Error :**

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on shipping-db to execute command { eval: "function() { return db.Items.find(); }" }' on server localhost:27017. 

The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on shipping-db to execute command { eval: \"function() { return db.Items.find(); }\" }", "code" : 13 }
```

`rs1:PRIMARY> db.system.users.find({})` is empty.

mongo.conf

```
storage:
    journal:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: Check the following question. It might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787610/mongodb-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command